Question about proof of Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem for the case of $\sigma$-finite positive measure.
I am asked to proof the following Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem for the case of $\sigma$-finite positive measure:

Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$, and let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$. Then there are unique positive measures $\nu_a$ and $\nu_s$ on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ such that
(a) $\nu_a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$,
(b) $\nu_s$ is singular with respect to $\mu$, and
(c) $\nu=\nu_a+\nu_s$.
The decomposition $\nu=\nu_a+\nu_s$ is called the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$.

For this post, let us forget the uniqueness. I tried myself to prove the existence of such $\nu_a$ anhd $\nu_s$, but I am not sure whether my attempt is correct or not, especially the final part of showing the absolute continuity of $\nu_a$ with respect to $\mu$. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check my work (especially for the last part of Step 3)! Thank you very much!
Here is my attempt:

Proof of Existence$\quad$ Since $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$, we can write
$$
X = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}D_i,
$$
where $D_i\in\mathscr{A}$ and $\nu(D_i)<+\infty$ for all $i$.
Step 1$\quad$ Consider the set $\mathscr{A}_k$ defined by $\mathscr{A}_k = \{A\in\mathscr{A}:A\subseteq D_k\}$. We show that $\mathscr{A_k}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $D_k$.

Clearly, $D_k\in\mathscr{A}_k$.

Let $A\in\mathscr{A}_k$, then $A\in\mathscr{A}$ and $A\subseteq D_k$, and thus $D_k\backslash A = A^c\bigcap D_k$, so that $D_k\backslash A\in\mathscr{A}_k$.

Let $\{A_i\}$ be a sequence of sets that belong to $\mathscr{A}_k$, then $A_i\in\mathscr{A}$ and $A_i\subseteq D_k$ for all $i$, and thus $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\in\mathscr{A}$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\subseteq D_k$, so that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\in\mathscr{A}_k$.


Step 2$\quad$ Now let $k$ be a positive integer and consider the restrictions of $\mu$ and $\nu$ to the spaces $(D_k,\mathscr{A}_k)$. Then $\mu|_{(D_k,\mathscr{A}_k)}$ is a positive measure and $\nu|_{(D_k,\mathscr{A}_k)}$ is a finite positive measure on $(D_k,\mathscr{A}_k)$. Define $\mathscr{N}_{\mu_k}$ by
$$
\mathscr{N}_{\mu_k} = \{B_k\in\mathscr{A}_k:\mu(B_k)=0\},
$$
and choose a sequence $\{B_{k,j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of sets in $\mathscr{N}_{\mu_k}$ such that
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty}\nu(B_{k,j}) = \sup\{\nu(B_k):B_k\in\mathscr{N}_{\mu_k}\}.
$$
Let $N_k=\bigcup_jB_{k,j}$ and let $N=\bigcup_kN_k$. Define $\nu_a$ and $\nu_s$ by $\nu_a(A)=\nu(A\bigcap N^c)$ and $\nu_s(A) = \nu(A\bigcap N)$.
Step 3$\quad$ We prove that the $\nu_a$ and $\nu_s$ defined in Step 2 form a Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$.

$\nu=\nu_a+\nu_s$: $\nu(A) = \nu(A\bigcap N^c) + \nu(A\bigcap N) = \nu_a(A)+\nu_s(A)$.

$\nu_s$ is singular with respect to $\mu$: The countable subadditivity of $\mu$ implies
$$
0\leq\mu(N)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(N_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}B_{k,j}\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_{k,j})=0,
$$
and so $\mu(N)=0$. We also have $\nu_s(N^c)=\nu(\emptyset)=0$. So $\nu_s$ is singular with respect to $\mu$.

$\nu_a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$: Note that
$$
\nu(N_k) = \sup\{\nu(B_k):B_k\in\mathscr{N}_{\mu_k}\},
$$
so each $\mathscr{A}_k$-measurable subset $B_k$ of $D_k\backslash N_k$ that satisfies $\mu(B_k)=0$ also satisfies $\nu(B_k)=0$, because otherwise $N_k\bigcup B_k$ would belong to $\mathscr{N}_{\mu_k}$ and satisfy $\nu(N_k\bigcup B)>\nu(N_k)$. Now, if $B$ is an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subset of $N^c = \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k^c$, then it must be an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subset of $D_k\backslash N_k$ for some $k$, and so $B$ is an $\mathscr{A}_k$-measurable subset of $D_k\backslash N_k$. So if this set $B$ satisfies $\mu(B)=0$ then it must also satisfy $\nu(B)=0$. Define
$$
\mathscr{N}_{\mu} = \{B\in\mathscr{A}:\mu(B)=0\}.
$$
Note that $N=\bigcup_k\bigcup_jB_{k,j}\in\mathscr{A}$ so that $N^c\in\mathscr{A}$. Let $B\in\mathscr{N}_{\mu}$, then $\mu(B)=0$. Also, $B\bigcap N^c\in\mathscr{A}$, $B\bigcap N^c\subseteq N^c$, and $0\leq\mu(B\bigcap N^c)\leq\mu(B)=0$ so that $\mu(B\bigcap N^c)=0$. Therefore, $\nu_a(B)=\nu(B\bigcap N^c)=0$. Hence, $\nu_a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.




Here are some related definitions:

Definition$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be positive measures on $(X,\mathscr{A})$. Then $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ if each set $A$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$ and satisfies $\mu(A)=0$ also satisfies $\nu(A)=0$.


Definition$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space. A positive measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ is concentrated on the $\mathscr{A}$-measurable set $E$ if $\mu(E^c)=0$.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are positive measures on $(X,\mathscr{A})$. Then $\nu$ is singular with respect to $\mu$ (or $\mu$ is singular with respect to $\nu$) if there is an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable set $E$ such that $\mu$ is concentrated on $E$ and $\nu$ is concentrated on $E^c$.


Thank you very much for any help!

There is definitely something wrong, starting from "Now, if $B$ is an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subset of $N^c=\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k^c$, ....". But I don't know how to fix it.

I updated my attempt in Step 3 $\nu_a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. I feel this is better, but am still not confident. Could someone please help my check? Thank you very much!

In the sentence you mention, $N_k^c$, the complement is relative to $X$, not $D_k$, therefore the rest of the sentence is wrong. I think it would be easier to prove it for finite measure, since you can make the $D_k$ disjoint anyways, I would only use $N_k$ and $D_k$ for that part of the proof.

@P.Quinton Thanks a lot for your comment. By "the rest of the sentence is wrong", do you mean the sentence in my first comment or the current version of my proof?

@P.Quinton In fact, the proof for finite (positive) measure is given by the textbook. The proof for $\sigma$-finite (positive) measure is assigned as an exercise.

Then the simplest proof would be to make the $D_k$ disjoint and work on them individually, then the rest is the same (you can and should actually use the fact from the textbook, because you want to keep the proof elementary and isolate the important things)

Thanks a lot @P.Quinton! That will indeed simplify the proof. But I couldn't see how my proof is wrong:"if $B$ is an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subset of $N^c = \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k^c$, then it must be an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subset of $D_k\backslash N_k$ for some $k$...." Isn't this argument valid (because otherwise we would have a contradiction)?

Take for instance $B=N$, this may contain points from all of the $D_k$ and therefore it cannot be a subset of any one of them $D_k$ (if they are disjoint, which they can be).

@P.Quinton But $B$ cannot be equal to $N$, because $B$ is assumed to be an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable subset of $N^c$.

Yeah my bad, I meant $B=N^c$.

@P.Quinton Ohhhh, I get your point! Yeah I was wrong. Thank you so much for pointing it out!
